# Given the derivative is $g'(x) = x^3(x-2)^2(x+8)^9$, where does $g$ have a local maximum?

Tags: calculus

> Consider a function $g(x)$ with derivative $g'(x) = x^3(x-2)^2(x+8)^9$. For what values of $x$ does $g(x)$ have a local maximum?

I know the answer is -8, but how do you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

A differentiable function has a local maximum at all the points where the derivative **switches from positive to negative**.

In this case, $g'(x) = x^3 (x-2)^2 (x+8)^9$ switches from positive to negative at $x = -8$, then switches from negative to positive at $x = 0$, then stays positive at $x = 2$.  So the only local max is $x = -8$.

**Further Explanation**

Note $x^3 (x-2)^2 (x+8)^9$ is an even polynomial, so it goes off to $+\infty$ on the left and the right.  Then it has zeroes at $x = 0, x = 2, x = -8$.  When a polynomial has a factor $(x - a)^k$, then it switches sign if $k$ is odd and stays the same sign if $k$ is even.  Thus, $g'$ switches sign at $x = 0$ and $-8$, and stays the same at $x = 2$.

Comment: But how do you find the critical numbers here.

Comment: @Dylan You mean the critical points? The critical points are just the zeroes of $g'$.

Comment: Wait can I just set x-2 = 0 and x + 8 = 0 to find the critical points?

Comment: How do you know that it's switching from positive ot negative at x= -8 and that its switching from negative to positive at x = 0?

Comment: @Dylan I added a "Further Explanation".  Does this help?  If you've had pre-calculus you may remember this is how you graph a polynomial function.